# A bound on the nth prime.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there any combinatorial argument to show that the nth prime $p_n = \mathcal{O}(n^k)$ for fixed $k$ ? There is a problem in the book by Apostol to find upper bounds on $p_n$, the Prime Number Theorem and simple estimates can be used to prove that. I was wondering if a combinatorial argument could be used.

Comment: What do you mean combinatorial argument?Something which says for example that there is a number $<n^2$ whose residues upon division with the primes $\leq n$ are not zero?If you are looking something like this then the answer is no. But Erdos's proof of Chebyshev 's theorem is in a sence "combinatorial" actually.

Comment: I am just looking for a combinatorial argument to put a polynomial like upper bound on the nth prime number. I'll look at Erdos' proof. Thanks.